# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'SelectedUserInteractionTypes'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, ienumerable, html.dropdownlistfor

I´m implementing an webapp with Asp.Net, C# and a MVC.

I´m trying to implement a DropDownListFor in my View but the following error occurs:

> There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key
>   'SelectedUserInteractionTypes'.

I already searched for some solutions but I still don´t get it.

My View looks like: (The First DropDownListFor works fine but the second doesn´t)

```
    <thead>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
    <tr class="filters">
        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Zeit"></th>
        <th>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().SelectedUser, Model.FirstOrDefault().AvailableUser, new { @id = "userFilter", @class = "selectpicker", @multiple = "mulitple", data_live_search = "true"})</th>
        <th>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().SelectedUserInteractionTypes, Model.FirstOrDefault().AvailableUserInteractionTypes_ID, new { @id = "interactionTypeFilter", @class = "selectpicker", @multiple = "mulitple", data_live_search = "true" })</th>
        <th><input type="submit" value="Filtern" class="btn btn-default" /></th>
        <th><input onclick="test()" type="submit" value="Zurücksetzen" class="btn btn-default" /></th>
    </tr>
    }
```

My UserInteractionViewModels looks like:

```
        public MultiSelectList AvailableUser { get; set; }

    private List<int> _selectedUser = new List<int>();

    public List<int> SelectedUser
    {
        get { return _selectedUser; }
        set { _selectedUser = value; }
    }

    public MultiSelectList AvailableUserInteractionTypes_ID { get; set; }

    private List<int> _selectedUserInteractionTypes = new List<int>();

    public List<int> SelectedUserInteractionTypes
    {
        get { return _selectedUserInteractionTypes; }
        set { _selectedUserInteractionTypes = value; }
    }
```

And at least here is my Index method of the controller where is use the selectedLists

```
       public ActionResult Index()
    {

        UserInteractionViewModels userInteractionViewModels = new UserInteractionViewModels();
        userInteractionViewModels.AvailableUser = new MultiSelectList(db.AspNetUsers.ToList(), "Id", "Email", userInteractionViewModels.SelectedUser);
        //userInteractionViewModels.AvailableUserInteractionTypes_ID = new MultiSelectList(db.UserInteractionTypes.ToList(), "UserInteractionTypes_Id", "Name", userInteractionViewModels.SelectedUserInteractionTypes);

        List<UserInteractionViewModels> userInteractions = new List<UserInteractionViewModels>();
        string setValue = Request["userFilter"];
        foreach (UserInteraction userInteraction in db.UserInteractions.ToList())
        {
            userInteractions.Add(new UserInteractionViewModels()
            {
                AspNetUser = userInteraction.AspNetUser,
                Time = userInteraction.Time,
                Description = userInteraction.Description,
                SelectedUser = userInteractionViewModels.SelectedUser,
                AvailableUser = userInteractionViewModels.AvailableUser
            });
        }
        //db.UserInteractions.Include(u => u.AspNetUser).Include(u => u.UserInteractionType);

        // Hier: Überprüfen, ob nach einem bestimmten String gefiltert worden ist

        //if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))

        if (userInteractionViewModels.SelectedUser.Count() > 0)
        {
            string test2 = userInteractionViewModels.AvailableUser.FirstOrDefault().ToString();
            foreach (UserInteraction userInteraction in db.UserInteractions.Where(x => x.AspNetUser.Id.Equals(userInteractionViewModels.SelectedUser.FirstOrDefault().ToString())))
            {
                userInteractions.Add(new UserInteractionViewModels()
                {
                    AspNetUser = userInteraction.AspNetUser,
                    Time = userInteraction.Time,
                    Description = userInteraction.Description,
                    SelectedUser = userInteractionViewModels.SelectedUser,
                    AvailableUser = userInteractionViewModels.AvailableUser
                });
            }
            //List<UserInteractionViewModels> userInteractions = db.UserInteractions.Where(x => x.AspNetUser.Email.ToLower().Contains(searchString.ToLower())).ToListAsync());
            //userInteractions = userInteractions.Where(x => x.AspNetUser.Email.ToLower().Contains(searchString.ToLower()) || x.Description.ToLower().Contains(searchString.ToLower()) || x.Time.ToString().ToLower().Contains(searchString.ToLower()));
        }
        return View(userInteractions);
    }
```

Has anybody an idea what I can do to solve the problem? Thank you very much !

Comment: It means that the value of `AvailableUserInteractionTypes_ID` is `null`.

Comment: Thank you ! It means that in my controller the 4th line (which is actually commented out) does not work fine, right? When  commenting in this line it also doesn´t work but I have an idea !

Comment: And why in the world are you using `.FirstOrDefault()` in your expressions (that is never going to bind correctly when you submit)? And why are you using `MultiSelectList`?

Comment: It´s the first time I´m using MVC, C# and Asp.Net. I can´t write model.SelectedUserInteractionTypes. I dont know why.

Comment: Thank you very much ! Because of your clue I could solve my problem ! Do you have also a suggestion what I should write instead of .FirstOrDefault() ?